# How to get regex into XPath expressions via nu.XOM API?

Tags: java, regex, xom

I'd like to know if XOM allows regex in it's XPath expressions. As far as I know regex is only available in XPath 2.0 via the match() function. It seems that XOM doesn't support this function. Is their another way to use regex in XPath?

Answer (score 0):

It does not. XOM's XPath is based on Jaxen, which only supports XPath 1.0.